# Why are multiple requests being processed for a single browser request?

Tags: node.js

Note: I am very new to node, and I have a VERY simple node site running based upon this example (http://blog.falafel.com/Blogs/BasemEmara/basem-emara/2014/03/18/getting-started-with-node.js-for-windows)

My code is:

```
var http = require('http');
var reqCount = 0;
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    reqCount++;
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    console.log(reqCount);
    res.end('Request: ' + reqCount);
}).listen(3000);
```

In the browser I initially get 1, hit refresh and get 3, 5, 7

And in the console I am getting every int, two per request

Why is this executing twice for each request?

I also know that I will not be handling requests directly, but wanted to start basic and then include express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be `/favicon.ico` request done by your browser.

You can also print request url from `req` object to see that:

```
console.log(req.url);
```

Comment: You are absolutely correcct, first request is for the page, and the second is for the favicon.ico I tried to look at the full req object, and url got lost in the shuffle. Thanks